# Params require throwing param is missing or the value is empty:article

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

All, i am creating a rails api following a tutorial. I am running into issue using rails 6 and fast_jsonapi gem.

I have the following in my controller

```
module Api
module V1
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  def index
    articles = Article.all
    
   render json: ArticleSerializer.new(articles, options).serialized_json
  end
  
  def show
    article = Article.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
    render json: ArticleSerializer.new(article, options).serialized_json
  end
  
  
  def create
    article = Article.new(article_params)
    if article.save
      render json: ArticleSerializer.new(article).serialized_json
    else
      render json: {error: article.error.messages}, status: 422
    end
  end
  


  
   def update
    article = Article.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
    if article.update(article_params)
      render json: ArticleSerializer.new(articles,options).serialized_json
    else
      render json: {error: article.error.messages}, status: 422
    end
  end
  
  
   def destroy
    article = Article.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
    if article.destroy(article_params)
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: {error: article.error.messages}, status: 422
    end
  end
  
  private
  
  def article_params
    params.require(:articles).permit(:name, :image_url)
   # params.permit(:name, :image_url)
  end
  #compond document, pass in optional hash with additionalresources
  def options
    @options ||= {include:%i[reviews]}
  end
  
end
```

end
end

i am able to get Request, however, when i try to create a article for example with the following strong parameter

```
params.require(:articles).permit(:name, :image_url)
```

i get the following:
[image]

If i remove require and just add

```
params.permit(:name, :image_url)
```

Record is created but its empty

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "21",
    "type": "article",
    "attributes": {
        "name": null,
        "image_url": null,
        "slug": "article"
    },
    "relationships": {
        "reviews": {
            "data": []
          }
      }
  }
```

}

Any assistance on this?

here is my review controller:

```
module Api
 module V1
 class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
   def create
    review = Review.new(review_params)
    if article.save
      render json: ReviewSerializer.new(review).serialized_json
    else
      render json: {error: review.error.messages}, status: 422
    end
  end
  
  
  def destroy
    review = Review.find_by(params[:id])
    if review.destroy
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: {error: review.error.messages}, status: 422
    end
  end
  
  
  private
  
   def review_params
   # params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description, :score , :article_id )
     params.permit(:title, :description, :score , :article_id )
   end
  
  end
end
```

end

my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'pages#index'
namespace :api do
namespace :v1 do
resources :articles, param: :slug
  resources :reviews, only: [:create, :destroy]

 end

 end
  get '*path', to: 'pages#index', via: :all
end
```

Comment: Please add  the post request params or the entire log for the POST. You need to send the params to the server like { articles: { name: 'a', image_url: 'b'}}

Comment: I think, based on your code it needs to be `article:` not `articles:`, however the error would suggest otherwise, is there a typo in your code that you shared?

Comment: {
"name": "this is khemlallfirst create through api",
"image_url": "http://khemalllurl.com/url"
}

Comment: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: article):

app/controllers/api/v1/articles_controller.rb:54:in `article_params'
app/controllers/api/v1/articles_controller.rb:19:in `create'
Started POST "/api/v1/articles/" for 165.225.222.176 at 2021-03-10 13:56:46 -0500
Cannot render console from 165.225.222.176! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1

Comment: the issue appears to be in the view, not the controller. ```params is missing or empty :articles``` means that the form is not submitting anything to params[:articles] can you show us what the view looks like?

Comment: Sorry i am testing this through postman to verify my api is working fine before i start with the views

Comment: ah, okay, then can you please cite the request you are submitting to the api to test the create method?

Comment: { "name": "this is khemlallfirst create through api", "image_url": "khemalllurl.com/url" }

Comment: you have ```params.require(:articles)``` i think maybe you mean that to be ```params.require(:article)``` ?